# What blogs or websites cover historical or contemporary science?

Tags: discoveries, resource-recommendation

Apologies if this isn't quite the right place to ask this.

The popular science sites like [Wired](http://www.wired.com/) and [io9](http://io9.com/) are too biased and reactionary for my tastes. I'm looking for sites or blogs that cover historical and contemporary science without injecting the writer's bias or agendas.

Does anyone have any reading suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "covering historical science"? I can see how blogs can cover recent developments in science, but that wouldn't be historical.

Comment: @Conifold, _blog_ now usually describes a web site of a particular form rather than the original meaning of a log of websites recently visited, optionially with commentary.  So Harry likely means a site of that form which discusses historical (or contemporary) science.

Answer (score 2):

See links at [Online resources for history of physics](http://www.aip.org/history/links.html), [History and Philosophy of Biology Resources](https://home.comcast.net/~rmillstein1/philbio.html), [Chemical Heritage Foundation](http://archives.math.utk.edu/topics/history.html), [Math Archives: History](http://archives.math.utk.edu/topics/history.html) and [Websites relevant to the History of Mathematics](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/Links/), also [Teaching with Original Historical Sources in Mathematics](http://www.math.nmsu.edu/~history/) puts an interesting spin on it.

I like [Sean Carroll's blog](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/) on physics,  [Phil Plait's blog](http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy.html) on astronomy, and [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/) on mathematics, they occasionally write about historical issues. Some reputable science news sites are [Discover Magazine](http://discovermagazine.com/), [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/science/), [Science News](https://www.sciencenews.org/) and [Science Daily](https://www.sciencenews.org/), Discover Magazine also hosts [many blogs](http://discovermagazine.com/rss), so does [Scientific American](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/).

Comment: Let me add this: http://mathpages.com/home/ihistory.htm

Comment: Not a historical site *per se* but certainly useful: http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/